# How to add condition to component during xsl transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, heat

I am trying to add component condition in wix during xsl transformation that is applied during harvesting a dir. I tried this template but it is not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
                xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[MYPROP="1"]]></Condition>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Although the input to the heat.exe will be directory location and xml generation will be done by heat along with transformation I think the intermediate xml that serves as input will be

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="MyDir">
            <Component Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll_x86" Guid="06CF68DB-C4D3-45D3-8619-982C7963ADC6">
                <File Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll_x86" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.CefSharpDirx86)\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll" />

            </Component>

        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

         <Fragment>
                <DirectoryRef Id="MyDir">
                    <Component Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll_x86" Guid="06CF68DB-C4D3-45D3-8619-982C7963ADC6">
                        <File Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll_x86" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.CefSharpDirx86)\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll" />
                      <Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[MYPROP="1"]]></Condition>
                    </Component>

                </DirectoryRef>
            </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

I am new to the XSLT world. Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us an example of the input, and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k: have added the example of the input and the expected output

Comment: Your input is not in the `wix:` namespace, so your template does not match anything.

Comment: I have added the namespace.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***-- edited in response to clarification --***

Not sure what you mean by "not working". Certainly, you must place the new element in the same namespace as its parent in order to get the intended result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="wix:Condition"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="Condition" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
            <xsl:attribute name="level">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:text>MYPROP="1"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working: http://xsltransform.net/bFN1yai

Comment: I didn't know the rule of namespaces so some how the output was getting littered with all the different namespaces ..Anyway ..thanks for the solution..the transformation is working but the value is not getting wrapped into CDATA in my case .

Comment: "*the value is not getting wrapped into CDATA*" It does in my [demo](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1yai). Did you copy it exactly - specifically the `cdata-section-elements` attribute?

Comment: yes i did it..though it is not a problem i have a work around .. <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text> I have added this for now

Comment: You should not have to use such hack - but if your XSLT processor does not conform to the specs...

Comment: Wow!  What an awesome answer!  This is exactly what I needed.  The working example was very helpful to quickly determine if the transform would indeed work for my scenario.