# Wix Toolset - apply Directory Conditions to its files

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

Consider this Directory,

```
          <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="DirName">
          <Component Id="comp_MyProgramDir" Guid="FC0409CE-27E6-475E-B6C2-95E4B4C0223C" KeyPath="yes">
            <Condition><![CDATA[MyCondition]]></Condition>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
```

I have  to apply `MyCondition` to all children components of the Directory. Since it is a very big Directory containing many files, is there a way to avoid to write the condition for every component? The `Transitive` attribute is not helpful at all!

Comment: Use xslt to make that transform. I suggest you to add a tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="wix:Condition"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="Condition" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
            <xsl:attribute name="level">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:text>MyCondition</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[How to add condition to component during xsl transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628509/how-to-add-condition-to-component-during-xsl-transformation)